# HTML body does not scroll when content extends below the page

Tags: html, css, scroll

For some reason, even when I have content extending below the page, and overflow CSS, I cannot scroll down the page.  A scroll bar appears, but I cannot scroll down.  If you need any more code from the page than I provide, please let me know!

HTML of the content that extends below the window:

```
<div id="images">
<p>Here you will find some of my Photoshops!</p>
<img style = "top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-350px;" src="lufthansa747-8.jpg" width="720" height="460">
<img style = "top:100%;left:50%;margin-left:-350px;" src="advert.jpg" width="720" height="460">
```

CSS of the code for the areas that possibly affect the area:

```
#images p{
position: fixed;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -125px;
color: #1D60E2;
text-align: center;
}
#images img{
position: fixed;
}
body {
background-color: #C2DFFF;
min-height: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I think it's because you use `position: fixed` property**. If you wanna scroll to see all the content, I guess you should remove it or replace it with absolute positionning.

```
#images p{
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -125px;
color: #1D60E2;
text-align: center;
}
#images img{
position: absolute;
}
body {
background-color: #C2DFFF;
min-height: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

The real question is : what are you trying to achieve ? Because in most case, your current CSS won't be the solution :)

Comment: Setting position:absolute worked, thank you very much!  Can't accept it as the official answer yet, but once I can, I certainly will!

Comment: Thank you, but remember to read some docs about CSS properties *before* using it ;)

Comment: And by the way, you shouldn't use inline CSS (in your HTML elements).